# Generating a star rating automatically?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to find some way to convert a number 1 - 5 into a star rating, which can also accomodate decimals, like 4.3 or 3.34, and be very precise (like on Amazon.com). The rating doesn't have to be usable, it just has to be a static image. Any help?

I'm fine with using PHP or jQuery, whichever it needs to be.

Comment: Are you trying to display this or generate the number?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Amazon has only full/half-star rating displays. They use a sprite that has two relevant sections: one ten-star section with 5 segments filled, and one ten-star section with 4.5 segments filled. They position that background image so that a certain number of full segments are displayed, and choose which section to use depending on whether there's a half star or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an image that is white with transparent star cutouts.  Then place that over the top of a yellow div of a given length.  Lets say your image was 100px wide.  If you had a 3 star rating you would make the yellow div 100*(3/5) and 3 of the stars would be filled in.

EDIT: 
A similar idea. You could have an image with all 5 stars on it.  Place this image within a div with overflow:hidden.  Then you set the width of the div the same way as above.  The smaller the div the less stars you'll see.

EDIT2:
Fiddle just for fun.  All the granularity you could ask for.
http://jsfiddle.net/qFMyC/

Answer (score 3):

This must be sufficient for your purpose:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this *ages* ago. I was obsessed with not using JS. It needs some work, but I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

http://yefomit.com/internet/simple_css_rater

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping you mean turning the 1 -5 value into an actual star representation.

It depends how granular you want to be, I think Amazon's is accurate to tenth's (0.1), this is probably achieved server side to save on client load and take advantage of caching the images; but it could be done client side.

@kingjiv posted a good client side solution but for server side:

If you're not too worried about granularity you could create 11 images 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 etc. etc. and pass the value into the image src attribute. This would serve the right image and they'd be nicely cached for re-use over and over on your pages.

If you want to be really granular though you could create them in code server side, cache them on creation each time ready for quickly serving afterwards. With this method you could go to whatever degree of accuracy took your fancy.

For PHP I'd recommend looking at Imagik

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is to create 2 divs and put them on top of each other.

On the bottom div you set the width equal to the width of 5 stars. So, if your star is 50px wide, your bottom div is 250px wide.

On the top div you use the same star with a different color. Then you set the width of that div in php or javascript to 50 * $decimalStarRating.